# Homogenize reads length

Tags: python, perl, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have a data set of paired-end reads in fastq files which length ranges from 300 to 414 bp (fungal ITS2 sequences). 
I want all my reads (few millions) to be 414 long by padding with Ns the 3' end of the shorter reads. So if a read is 400 bp long, I want it to be 414 long by adding 14 Ns at the end of the sequence.
Does anybody know a python / perl script able to perform that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BioPython`. You might want to change the `default_phred_score_for_N` value and/or add behaviour if the sequence is longer than 414 bp.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq

path = r'C:\path\to\file.fastq'
default_phred_score_for_N = 60

def pad_sequence(record):
    sequence = str(record.seq)
    if len(sequence) < 414:
        #pad sequence
        padding_length = 414 - len(sequence)
        sequence += 'N' * padding_length

        # pad annotation
        annotation = record.letter_annotations['phred_quality']
        annotation  += [default_phred_score_for_N] * padding_length
        record.letter_annotations = {}

        record.seq = Seq.Seq(sequence)
        record.letter_annotations = {'phred_quality': annotation}
        return record
    return record


padded_sequences = (pad_sequence(record) for record in \
                    SeqIO.parse(path, 'fastq'))

SeqIO.write(padded_sequences, "padded.fastq", 'fastq')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str .= 'N' x (414 - length($str));
```